# shell bash-to to sed with a string that includes "

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to replace some text with a string that contains a variable and quotation marks, i.e. a string like:

```
test "$x" "1" "0" ""
```

where x is a parameter from an array.

I am not sure what to do as usually I would just use "" around the replacement string value so that it expands the x value, but obviously that wont work as my string contains ""
Her is my command so far:

```
cat $FILE | sed 's|/#replace|test "'"$x"'" "1" "0" "" '|g' > $NEW_FILE
```

but that doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I count an odd number of single quotes, so I guess the single quote before |g is superfluous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version seems to do what you want:

```
$ x=ABC ; echo '/#replace' | sed 's|/#replace|test "'"$x"'" "1" "0" "" |g' 
test "ABC" "1" "0" ""
```

The sed command consists of three strings.  For clarity, I have added spaces between them here:

```
's|/#replace|test "' "$x" '" "1" "0" "" |g'  # Don't try to use this form.  It is for explication only.
```

The first and third parts of the sed command are in single quotes to prevent shell interpretation.  The middle string which is the only in double-quotes and that is so that `$x` is interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sed:

```
sed "s|/#replace|test \"$x\" \"1\" \"0\" \"\"|g" "$FILE" > "$NEW_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

In that way you should do:

```
FILEPATH="/path/to/SourceFile"
sed 's|search|replace|' $FILEPATH  > /path/to/EditedFile-new
```